# Looking to pull a key called eventDateTime from a CouchDB doc

Tags: javascript, database, function, asynchronous, couchdb

I'm looking into pulling a key off all of my CouchDB documents called `eventDateTime`, which tracks a POST'ed event's date/time on the database.

But is there a way I could just pass the data tracked here under "newWorkout" too, the /calender route as an array?

```
export const createNewWorkout = history => (dispatch, getState) => {
  dispatch({ type: WORKOUT_SAVE_STARTED })



 const newWorkout = getState().newWorkout.data

  fetch(`${url}progress`, {
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json"
    },
    method: "POST",
    body: JSON.stringify(newWorkout)
  })
    .then(res => {
      console.log("res: ", res)
      return res.json()
    })
    .then(saveResponse => {
      console.log("in happy", JSON.stringify(saveResponse))
      if (!saveResponse.ok) {
        dispatch({
          type: NEW_WORKOUT_SAVE_FAILED,
          payload: "Could not save the workout."
        })
      } else {
        dispatch({ type: NEW_WORKOUT_SAVE_SUCCEEDED })
        history.push("/calender")
      }
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.log(JSON.stringify("ERRRRRR", err))
      dispatch({
        type: NEW_WORKOUT_SAVE_FAILED,
        payload:
          "Unexpected error prevented us from saving the workout. Please try again."
      })
    })
}
```